# How to pass parameters to a stored procedure that returns multiple records

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

How to pass parameters to a stored procedure that returns multiple records using EF6 - `DbContext` with SQL Server 2016 stored procedure having encrypted columns?

Using EF 6.1.3, SQL Server 2016 - AlwaysEncrypted (deterministic)

There are a [few articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider) that talk about using ADO .NET 4.6 to accomplish this by using command, parameter objects, but I could not find a way to do it from my EF `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//make sure to provide the actual datatype and size on the parameter   
//you can use reflection on the entity to dynamically get/set the property info by a common function.

var paratmeterNames = new StringBuilder();
string paratmeterNamesUpdated = null;

if (lastName != null)
{
    var lastNameParam = new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 60) {Value = lastName};
    parameterList.Add(lastNameParam);
    paratmeterNames.Append("@lastName,");
}

if (firstName != null)
{
    var firstNameParameter = new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30) {Value = firstName};
    parameterList.Add(firstNameParameter);
    paratmeterNames.Append("@firstName,");
}

if (paratmeterNames != null && paratmeterNames.Length > 0)
{
    paratmeterNamesUpdated = paratmeterNames.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
}

var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("exec sp_name " + paratmeterNamesUpdated, parameterList.ToArray()).ToList();

//this will make below **calls to SQL DB:**
//exec sp_describe_parameter_encryption N'exec sp_name @lastName,@firstName',N'@lastName varchar(60),@firstName varchar(30)'
//exec sp_executesql N'exec sp_name @lastName,@firstName',N'@lastName varchar(60),@firstName varchar(30)',@lastName=0x01A2256C34F97,@firstName=0x018EE4BD11BA7
```